# Can we see everything?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

OK so light bends and light is color, so if I was in a hallway with both sides closed and a mirror on each end of the hallway that takes up all of the wall facing me, a mirror above me that takes up the whole ceiling , and the other mirrors tilted slightly up towards the mirror above me. Then if I look into the mirror in front of me and light bounces off that mirror and hits the mirror above me which reflects to the mirror behind me, in the mirror I'm facing would I be able to see endless light duplicates of me. Would it be any different if there was a mirror on the ground that covered the whole hallway? So I guess what I'm asking is that if you had photons inside of a glass prism then where does that light go?

Comment: Please look at my profile before voting commenting answering it or leaving a comment and please ask before you edit

Comment: That's... not how Stack Exchange works, Zachary. Content can be edited - for example to improve the grammar or spelling - by anyone who's earned that privilege.

Comment: K it's just someone was messing around with my last question so I deleted it

Comment: Regarding your previous post, if it was deliberate "messing around" with no good intention behind it, you could flag it. There is  a record of the edits users make, I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is much different in principle, from holding a mirror in your hand and looking at yourself in another mirror.

After each bounce, the reflections will lose their intensity and they will increasingly lose  focus/ sharpness. The image will eventually fade away, as the mirror never reflects 100 percent of the light. If you have a larger distance between yourself and the mirrors, as I think your question implies, this increases the rate of this fade out of the original image and you will also get less reflections than you would in my above paragraph.